# Entity Framework: Using multiple Strategies

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, database-migration

Is it possible to use multiple strategies for `Database Setinitializer` in EF 6.1.2 ?

I want to use `createdatabaseifnotexists`, its seed to add initialisation data and also want to  use `DbMigrationsConfiguration` on same dbContext for migration purpose. How to use this together in same DBContext `Setinitializer`?

Reason is I am doing `Coded migration` so I have to use

```
Database.SetInitializer(
       new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<YourContext, Configuration>());
```

also,

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DMDbInitializer());
```

where `DMDbInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<DMDbContext>`

Comment: Are you using Code-First Approach?

Comment: `Seed` is called everytime a migration is run when using `DbMigrationsConfiguration`.  So change your `Seed` method to create / update data only where needed (e.g. create a role only if the role doesn't exist)

Comment: I dont want to use DbMigrationsConfiguration's seed to do that operation, which has to be excecuted only once while creating DB. Otherwise whenever there is a migration this operation will be repeated. I want to avoid to add additional check whether it's already exceuted or not.

Comment: @VikrantMore : Yes i am using Code-First approach.

Comment: Then have your `Seed` method check if it has already been run (could be as simple as checking to see if a table has any data in it).  Ultimately, I think you are going to end up with something way more complex trying to use multiple strategies than in accommodating first run in the `Seed`.